# Turtlebot Dashboard Warning : diagnostic_aggregator

Tags: ros, turtlebot-dashboard, diagnostic-aggregator, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am receiving a warning from my Turtlebot Dashboard:

```
Node: /diagnostic_aggregator
Time: 1328731882.669506934
Severity: Warn
Location: /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-diagnostics-1.6.1/debian/ros-electric-diagnostics/opt/ros/electric/stacks/diagnostics/diagnostic_aggregator/src/analyzer_group.cpp:AnalyzerGroup::init:109
Published Topics: /rosout

Analyzer specification should now include the package name. You are using a deprecated API. Please switch from GenericAnalyzer to diagnostic_aggregator/GenericAnalyzer in your Analyzer specification.
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this warning, and how to fix it?  Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12940/turtlebot-dashboard-warning-:--diagnostic_aggregator/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your `diagnostic_aggregator` parameters, instead of:

```
type: AnalyzerGroup
```

change it to:

```
type: diagnostic_aggregator/AnalyzerGroup
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-02-08**:
ticket filed: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/124

**Comment by [Jack Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/10321/jack-fu/) on 2014-05-05**:
Where exactly can I make this change?